# regex Python match large list of strings

Tags: python, regex

I have a large list of strings which include whitespaces in them (e.g. "New York", "United States", "North Carolina", "United Arab Emirates", "United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland" ...and around 5000+ such strings).

And I have a large text in which may include any of these these strings *(e.g. "I went to New York on my way to North Carolina, and eventually will be going to United Arab Emirates.")*

What is the best way to efficiently use regular expression to detect the presence of these strings within my text?

Or maybe should I think about it the other way around, such that I extract bigrams from the text and see which strings within this list match these bigrams?

---

#### EDIT:

After an interesting discussion with VoronoiPotato, I began to think that it is better to index all the tokens of the items of the large string list, and I managed to do this with the function:

```
def indexing_list(li):
    index_dict={}
    for i in rl(li):
        words=li[i].split()
        for j in rl(words):
            index=complex(i,j)
            word=words[j].lower()
            try:
                index_dict[word].append(index)
            except:
                index_dict[word]=[index]
    return index_dict
```

And tried with this list:

```
[u'United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland', u'Democratic People\u2019s Republic of Korea', u'Democratic Republic of the Congo', u'Lao People\u2019s Democratic Republic', u'Saint Vincent and the Grenadines', u'United Republic of Tanzania', u'Iran (Islamic Republic of)', u'Central African Republic', u'Islamic Republic of Iran', u'United States of America', u'Bosnia and Herzegovina', u'Libyan Arab Jamahiriya', u'Saint Kitts and Nevis', u'Sao Tome and Principe', u'Syrian Arab Republic', u'United Arab Emirates', u'Antigua and Barbuda', u'Trinidad and Tobago', u'Dominican Republic', u'Russian Federation', u'Brunei Darussalam', u'Equatorial Guinea', u'Republic of Korea', u'Marshall Islands', u'Papua New Guinea', u'Solomon Islands', u'ComodRivadavia', u'Port-au-Prince', u'DumontDUrville', u'Czech Republic', u'United Kingdom', u'Dar es Salaam', u'Cambridge Bay', u'Coral Harbour', u'Port of Spain', u'Santo Domingo', u'St Barthelemy', u'Swift Current', u'Ujung Pandang', u'Yekaterinburg', u'South Georgia', u'C\xf4te d\u2019Ivoire', u"Cote d'Ivoire", u'Guinea-Bissau', u'Liechtenstein', u'United States', u'Johannesburg', u'Buenos Aires', u'Rio Gallegos', u'Blanc-Sablon', u'Campo Grande', u'Danmarkshavn', u'Dawson Creek', u'Indianapolis', u'North Dakota', u'Rankin Inlet', u'Scoresbysund', u'Longyearbyen', u'Kuala Lumpur', u'Antananarivo', u'Port Moresby', u'Burkina Faso', u'Saudi Arabia', u'Sierra Leone', u'South Africa', u'Turkmenistan', u'Addis Ababa', u'Brazzaville', u'Ouagadougou', u'El Salvador', u'Los Angeles', u'Mexico City', u'Pangnirtung', u'Porto Velho', u'Puerto Rico', u'Rainy River', u'Tegucigalpa', u'Thunder Bay', u'Yellowknife', u'Ho Chi Minh', u'Krasnoyarsk', u'Novosibirsk', u'Ulaanbaatar', u'Vladivostok', u'Broken Hill', u'Isle of Man', u'Kaliningrad', u'Guadalcanal', u'Afghanistan', u'Cock Island', u'El Salvador', u'Netherlands', u'New Zealand', u'Philippines', u'Saint Lucia', u'Switzerland', u'Timor-Leste', u'Casablanca', u'Libreville', u'Lubumbashi', u'Nouakchott', u'Porto-Novo', u'Costa Rica', u'Fort Wayne', u'Grand Turk', u'Guadeloupe', u'Hermosillo', u'Petersburg', u'Louisville', u'Monticello', u'Martinique', u'Montevideo', u'Montserrat', u'Paramaribo', u'Porto Acre', u'Rio Branco', u'St Vincent', u'Whitehorse', u'Antarctica', u'South Pole', u'Choibalsan', u'Phnom Penh', u'Ulan Bator', u'Cape Verde', u'Queensland', u'Yancowinna', u'Bratislava', u'Copenhagen', u'Luxembourg', u'San Marino', u'Simferopol', u'Zaporozhye', u'Kiritimati', u'Yugoslavia', u'Azerbaijan', u'Bangladesh', u'Cape Verde', u'Costa Rica', u'Kazakhstan', u'Kyrgyzstan', u'Luxembourg', u'Madagascar', u'Mauritania', u'Micronesia', u'Montenegro', u'Mozambique', u'San Marino', u'Seychelles', u'Tajikistan', u'Uzbekistan', u'Bujumbura', u'Mogadishu', u'Anchorage', u'Araguaina', u'Catamarca', u'Boa Vista', u'Chihuahua', u'Fortaleza', u'Glace Bay', u'Goose Bay', u'Guatemala', u'Guayaquil', u'Tell City', u'Vincennes', u'Menominee', u'Monterrey', u'New Salem', u'Sao Paulo', u'St Thomas', u'Vancouver', u'Ashkhabad', u'Chongqing', u'Chungking', u'Hong Kong', u'Jerusalem', u'Kamchatka', u'Pontianak', u'Pyongyang', u'Qyzylorda', u'Samarkand', u'Singapore', u'Vientiane', u'Jan Mayen', u'Reykjavik', u'St Helena', u'Australia', u'Lord Howe', u'Melbourne', u'Greenwich', u'Amsterdam', u'Bucharest', u'Gibraltar', u'Ljubljana', u'Mariehamn', u'Podgorica', u'Stockholm', u'Volgograd', u'Christmas', u'Kerguelen', u'Mauritius', u'Enderbury', u'Galapagos', u'Kwajalein', u'Marquesas', u'Pago Pago', u'Rarotonga', u'Tongatapu', u'Argentina', u'Australia', u'Guatemala', u'Indonesia', u'Lithuania', u'Mauritius', u'Nicaragua', u'Singapore', u'Sri Lanka', u'Swaziland', u'Macedonia', u'Venezuela', u'Blantyre', u'Djibouti', u'El Aaiun', u'Freetown', u'Gaborone', u'Khartoum', u'Kinshasa', u'Monrovia', u'Ndjamena', u'Sao Tome', u'Timbuktu', u'Windhoek', u'Anguilla', u'La Rioja', u'San Juan', u'San Luis', u'Asuncion', u'Atikokan', u'Barbados', u'Dominica', u'Edmonton', u'Eirunepe', u'Ensenada', u'Kentucky', u'Mazatlan', u'Miquelon', u'Montreal', u'New York', u'Resolute', u'Santiago', u'Shiprock', u'St Johns', u'St Kitts', u'St Lucia', u'Winnipeg', u'Ashgabat', u'Calcutta', u'Damascus', u'Dushanbe', u'Istanbul', u'Jayapura', u'Katmandu', u'Makassar', u'Sakhalin', u'Shanghai', u'Tashkent', u'Tel Aviv', u'Atlantic', u'Adelaide', u'Brisbane', u'Canberra', u'Lindeman', u'Tasmania', u'Victoria', u'Belgrade', u'Brussels', u'Budapest', u'Chisinau', u'Guernsey', u'Helsinki', u'Sarajevo', u'Tiraspol', u'Uzhgorod', u'Auckland', u'Funafuti', u'Honolulu', u'Johnston', u'Pitcairn', u'Barbados', u'Botswana', u'Bulgaria', u'Cambodia', u'Cameroon', u'Colombia', u'Djibouti', u'Dominica', u'Ethiopia', u'Holy See', u'Honduras', u'Kiribati', u'Malaysia', u'Maldives', u'Mongolia', u'Pakistan', u'Paraguay', u'Portugal', u'Slovakia', u'Slovenia', u'Suriname', u'Thailand', u'Tanzania', u'Viet Nam', u'Zimbabwe', u'Anguilla', u'Abidjan', u'Algiers', u'Conakry', u'Kampala', u'Mbabane', u'Nairobi', u'Tripoli', u'America', u'Antigua', u'Cordoba', u'Mendoza', u'Tucuman', u'Ushuaia', u'Caracas', u'Cayenne', u'Chicago', u'Curacao', u'Detroit', u'Godthab', u'Grenada', u'Halifax', u'Indiana', u'Marengo', u'Winamac', u'Iqaluit', u'Managua', u'Marigot', u'Moncton', u'Nipigon', u'Noronha', u'Phoenix', u'Rosario', u'Tijuana', u'Toronto', u'Tortola', u'Yakutat', u'McMurdo', u'Rothera', u'Baghdad', u'Bahrain', u'Bangkok', u'Bishkek', u'Colombo', u'Irkutsk', u'Jakarta', u'Karachi', u'Kashgar', u'Kolkata', u'Kuching', u'Magadan', u'Nicosia', u'Rangoon', u'Tbilisi', u'Thimphu', u'Yakutsk', u'Yerevan', u'Bermuda', u'Madeira', u'Stanley', u'Andorra', u'Belfast', u'Tallinn', u'Vatican', u'Vilnius', u'Mayotte', u'Reunion', u'Chatham', u'Fakaofo', u'Gambier', u'Norfolk', u'Albania', u'Algeria', u'Armenia', u'Austria', u'Bahamas', u'Bahrain', u'Belarus', u'Belgium', u'Bolivia', u'Burundi', u'Comoros', u'Croatia', u'Denmark', u'Ecuador', u'Eritrea', u'Estonia', u'Finland', u'Georgia', u'Germany', u'Grenada', u'Hungary', u'Iceland', u'Ireland', u'Jamaica', u'Lebanon', u'Lesotho', u'Liberia', u'Morocco', u'Myanmar', u'Namibia', u'Nigeria', u'Moldova', u'Romania', u'Senegal', u'Somalia', u'Tunisia', u'Ukraine', u'Uruguay', u'Vanuatu', u'Asmara', u'Asmera', u'Bamako', u'Bangui', u'Banjul', u'Bissau', u'Douala', u'Harare', u'Kigali', u'Luanda', u'Lusaka', u'Malabo', u'Maputo', u'Maseru', u'Niamey', u'Belize', u'Bogota', u'Cancun', u'Cayman', u'Cuiaba', u'Dawson', u'Denver', u'Havana', u'Inuvik', u'Juneau', u'La Paz', u'Maceio', u'Manaus', u'Merida', u'Nassau', u'Recife', u'Regina', u'Virgin', u'Mawson', u'Palmer', u'Vostok', u'Arctic', u'Almaty', u'Anadyr', u'Aqtobe', u'Beirut', u'Brunei', u'Harbin', u'Kuwait', u'Manila', u'Muscat', u'Riyadh', u'Saigon', u'Taipei', u'Tehran', u'Thimbu', u'Urumqi', u'Azores', u'Canary', u'Faeroe', u'Currie', u'Darwin', u'Hobart', u'Sydney', u'Europe', u'Athens', u'Berlin', u'Dublin', u'Jersey', u'Lisbon', u'London', u'Madrid', u'Geneva', u'Monaco', u'Moscow', u'Prague', u'Samara', u'Skopje', u'Tirane', u'Vienna', u'Warsaw', u'Zagreb', u'Zurich', u'Chagos', u'Comoro', u'Easter', u'Kosrae', u'Majuro', u'Midway', u'Noumea', u'Ponape', u'Saipan', u'Tahiti', u'Tarawa', u'Wallis', u'Andora', u'Angola', u'Belize', u'Bhutan', u'Brazil', u'Canada', u'Cyprus', u'France', u'Gambia', u'Greece', u'Guinea', u'Guyana', u'Israel', u'Jordan', u'Kuwait', u'Latvia', u'Malawi', u'Mexico', u'Monaco', u'Norway', u'Panama', u'Poland', u'Rwanda', u'Serbia', u'Sweden', u'Turkey', u'Tuvalu', u'Uganda', u'Zambia', u'Accra', u'Cairo', u'Ceuta', u'Dakar', u'Lagos', u'Tunis', u'Jujuy', u'Aruba', u'Bahia', u'Belem', u'Boise', u'Vevay', u'Thule', u'Casey', u'Davis', u'Syowa', u'Amman', u'Aqtau', u'Dacca', u'Dhaka', u'Dubai', u'Kabul', u'Macao', u'Macau', u'Qatar', u'Seoul', u'Tokyo', u'Faroe', u'Eucla', u'Perth', u'Malta', u'Minsk', u'Paris', u'Sofia', u'Vaduz', u'Cocos', u'Efate', u'Nauru', u'Palau', u'Samoa', u'Benin', u'Chile', u'China', u'Congo', u'Egypt', u'Gabon', u'Ghana', u'Haiti', u'India', u'Italy', u'Japan', u'Kenya', u'Libya', u'Malta', u'Nauru', u'Nepal', u'Niger', u'Palau', u'Qatar', u'Samoa', u'Spain', u'Sudan', u'Syria', u'Tonga', u'Yemen', u'Lome', u'Adak', u'Atka', u'Nuuk', u'Knox', u'Lima', u'Nome', u'Asia', u'Aden', u'Baku', u'Dili', u'Gaza', u'Hovd', u'Omsk', u'Oral', u'Zulu', u'Kiev', u'Oslo', u'Bonn', u'Riga', u'Rome', u'Mahe', u'Apia', u'Fiji', u'Guam', u'Niue', u'Truk', u'Wake', u'Chad', u'Cuba', u'Fiji', u'Iran', u'Iraq', u'Mali', u'Oman', u'Peru', u'Togo', u'GMT', u'Yap']
```

And then I started to analyze the text I have:

```
text='I went to New York and New Orleans and London and United States, Canada, and Egypt, Saudi Arabia'
text_words=text.split()
```

and tried to investigate each word separately:

```
for i in rl(text_words):
    tw=text_words[i].lower()
    print i
    print tw
    print index_dict.get(tw)
```

The methods seems fast, but I'm not sure how to take it further

Comment: Is it necessary to use regexes? Why not just case-insensitively check for these strings?

Comment: As with all regex questions, you need to flesh out what pattern you are trying to match. Are you looking to match only state/country names as your question implies?

Comment: @arxanas I'm not sure if there is something better than regex..I don't think it is s effecient to iterate over this huge list

Comment: @kevlar1818 primarily geographic information yes, but it may include people's names, so my criteria is "certain strings with whitespaces"

Comment: @hmghaly How do you think regex works internally? ;)

Comment: @hmghaly You haven't really got a choice regarding iterating across the whole list, unless you do some weird trie or graph.

Comment: @Izkata I know about the FSA and some of the underlying principles of regex, but of course there is more to it than I know :)

Comment: @arxanas I'm not actually aware of these (trie or graph) can you please explain?

Comment: @hmghaly They are data structures that tend to be useful in certain situations. A [graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(mathematics)) is a vague data structure in which elements are connected (either one-way or both-ways). A [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) is an implementation of a graph that could be used to break down your list into a more searchable version (maybe; I'm not good with this sort of thing).

Comment: Which is bigger, the text or the strings of countries?

Comment: The list of strings is bigger than the text I am investigating..

Comment: Now that you have an example, given how short the text string you're searching in is, I'd even more strongly say to go with HussainNagri's simple answer - don't do something clever that will be hard to figure out later.  Unless that example isn't representative of the length?

Comment: @Izkata the thing is that the iteration approach will take much more time than I can afford, so I have to come up with something better..

Comment: @hmghaly Keep in mind that anything more complicated is going to add overhead.  Have you actually tested the speed of the simple loop, and _know_ it's too slow?  `seems fast` isn't a very good measure at all.

Comment: Now Izkata, dictionaries are a form of hash and are often fast. There are a number of solutions that are more complex, more abstract and still exponentially faster despite their overhead. That being said I do agree with you, we need less guesswork and more science if you really want things to go faster. Use the stuff Archangel showed you to measure the run time of my stuff and compare it to other people's implementations.

There are however probably a few ways that can be cleaned up.

Comment: hmm I don't think you understood what I meant when I said index, this can be made much faster. You don't need the I or J next to the country name, as the structure of the object will maintain if you compose the objects correctly. 

[[{hash('United'):'United'},{hash('States'):'States'}],[{hash('Bolivia'):'Bolivia'}]]

By composing the objects this way with a unique key (and it's associated value) it allows us to near instantly compare strings.

Comment: I would test for speed though, because dictionary might already be doing what I'm talking about and that would explain any speed boosts.

Comment: @VoronoiPotato ah, ok, I'm trying to get it, not quite well though. Will I still need to traverse the entire list to get the hash of each token in the search text? Sorry for my confusion..

Comment: I have created a **more real time** dataset with your country list and a longer text body for searching... Results are really interesting. I can not test your ex. because i do not get what `rl` is in `for i in rl(li):`

Comment: Answer is updated again, with `Set` and @VoronoiPotato's capital letter aproach and resulted with the best timing (:

Comment: Sorry angel. It is basically range(len()) thanks

Comment: Answer updated (again) with addition of Token IUndexing approach. Also a possibly dangerous bug detected for some approahes

Answer (score 10):

```
whitespaces_list=['New York','United States', 'United Arab Emirates']
large_text="I went to New York on my way to North Carolina, and eventually will be going to United Arab Emirates."
for i in whitespaces_list:
    if i in large_text:
        print i," Exist in Large text"
```

are you looking for something like this ?

Comment: Well this is a bit too simple, and probably will not be efficient enough for a very large list...

Comment: @hmghaly Regexes aren't magical. They iterate over the list too

Comment: sure but they don't have to check every single letter, just enough to fulfill the requirement of the regex. That being said a regex for this probably would need to check every letter.

Comment: @VoronoiPotato maybe not exactly every character, we can just check at each word boundary the first character and if the following string is in the list, and know where the string ends, and start from this point... I know there is this look ahead in regex but I'm not actually sure how to use it..

Answer (score 7):

As most poeple said, it depends of your *text* and *city list*, and using `timeit` to compare methods is the best way to choose which way to go:

```
list = ['New York','United States', 'United Arab Emirates']
text = "I went to New York on my way to North Carolina, and eventually will be going to United Arab Emirates."
```

Timing with 1,000,000 loops and 5 repettions for each loop

```
timeit -n 1000000 -r 5 re.findall(token_regex, text)
1000000 loops, best of 5: 6.22 us per loop

timeit -n 1000000 -r 5 filter(lambda x: x in text, token_list)
1000000 loops, best of 5: 2.76 us per loop

def somefunc():
    for i in token_list:
        if i in text:
            pass

timeit -n 1000000 -r 5 somefunc()
1000000 loops, best of 5: 1.68 us per loop


t = [hash(x) for x in text.replace('.', '').replace(',','').split()] 
tl = [hash(x) for x in token_list]# this list contains single words, like "New" and "York" but not "New York"

def SomeFunc2():
    for x in tl:
        if x in t:
            pass

timeit -n 1000000 -r 5 SomeFunc2()
1000000 loops, best of 5: 6.26 us per loop

t = set([hash(x) for x in text.replace('.', '').replace(',','').split()])
tl = set(hash(x) for x in token_list])

timeit -n 1000000 -r 5 t.intersection(tl)
1000000 loops, best of 5: 1.75 us per loop
```

By using *your example data*, for loop usage looks pretty faster...But as i said, you must make your test with **more** real time data.

***EDIT***: Ok, i guess using more real time data is better, so i am re-calculating the result with following data set:

```
list = [u'United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland', u'Democratic People\u2019s Republic of Korea', u'Democratic Republic of the Congo', u'Lao People\u2019s Democratic Republic', u'Saint Vincent and the Grenadines', u'United Republic of Tanzania', u'Iran (Islamic Republic of)', u'Central African Republic', u'Islamic Republic of Iran', u'United States of America', u'Bosnia and Herzegovina', u'Libyan Arab Jamahiriya', u'Saint Kitts and Nevis', u'Sao Tome and Principe', u'Syrian Arab Republic', u'United Arab Emirates', u'Antigua and Barbuda', u'Trinidad and Tobago', u'Dominican Republic', u'Russian Federation', u'Brunei Darussalam', u'Equatorial Guinea', u'Republic of Korea', u'Marshall Islands', u'Papua New Guinea', u'Solomon Islands', u'ComodRivadavia', u'Port-au-Prince', u'DumontDUrville', u'Czech Republic', u'United Kingdom', u'Dar es Salaam', u'Cambridge Bay', u'Coral Harbour', u'Port of Spain', u'Santo Domingo', u'St Barthelemy', u'Swift Current', u'Ujung Pandang', u'Yekaterinburg', u'South Georgia', u'C\xf4te d\u2019Ivoire', u"Cote d'Ivoire", u'Guinea-Bissau', u'Liechtenstein', u'United States', u'Johannesburg', u'Buenos Aires', u'Rio Gallegos', u'Blanc-Sablon', u'Campo Grande', u'Danmarkshavn', u'Dawson Creek', u'Indianapolis', u'North Dakota', u'Rankin Inlet', u'Scoresbysund', u'Longyearbyen', u'Kuala Lumpur', u'Antananarivo', u'Port Moresby', u'Burkina Faso', u'Saudi Arabia', u'Sierra Leone', u'South Africa', u'Turkmenistan', u'Addis Ababa', u'Brazzaville', u'Ouagadougou', u'El Salvador', u'Los Angeles', u'Mexico City', u'Pangnirtung', u'Porto Velho', u'Puerto Rico', u'Rainy River', u'Tegucigalpa', u'Thunder Bay', u'Yellowknife', u'Ho Chi Minh', u'Krasnoyarsk', u'Novosibirsk', u'Ulaanbaatar', u'Vladivostok', u'Broken Hill', u'Isle of Man', u'Kaliningrad', u'Guadalcanal', u'Afghanistan', u'Cock Island', u'El Salvador', u'Netherlands', u'New Zealand', u'Philippines', u'Saint Lucia', u'Switzerland', u'Timor-Leste', u'Casablanca', u'Libreville', u'Lubumbashi', u'Nouakchott', u'Porto-Novo', u'Costa Rica', u'Fort Wayne', u'Grand Turk', u'Guadeloupe', u'Hermosillo', u'Petersburg', u'Louisville', u'Monticello', u'Martinique', u'Montevideo', u'Montserrat', u'Paramaribo', u'Porto Acre', u'Rio Branco', u'St Vincent', u'Whitehorse', u'Antarctica', u'South Pole', u'Choibalsan', u'Phnom Penh', u'Ulan Bator', u'Cape Verde', u'Queensland', u'Yancowinna', u'Bratislava', u'Copenhagen', u'Luxembourg', u'San Marino', u'Simferopol', u'Zaporozhye', u'Kiritimati', u'Yugoslavia', u'Azerbaijan', u'Bangladesh', u'Cape Verde', u'Costa Rica', u'Kazakhstan', u'Kyrgyzstan', u'Luxembourg', u'Madagascar', u'Mauritania', u'Micronesia', u'Montenegro', u'Mozambique', u'San Marino', u'Seychelles', u'Tajikistan', u'Uzbekistan', u'Bujumbura', u'Mogadishu', u'Anchorage', u'Araguaina', u'Catamarca', u'Boa Vista', u'Chihuahua', u'Fortaleza', u'Glace Bay', u'Goose Bay', u'Guatemala', u'Guayaquil', u'Tell City', u'Vincennes', u'Menominee', u'Monterrey', u'New Salem', u'Sao Paulo', u'St Thomas', u'Vancouver', u'Ashkhabad', u'Chongqing', u'Chungking', u'Hong Kong', u'Jerusalem', u'Kamchatka', u'Pontianak', u'Pyongyang', u'Qyzylorda', u'Samarkand', u'Singapore', u'Vientiane', u'Jan Mayen', u'Reykjavik', u'St Helena', u'Australia', u'Lord Howe', u'Melbourne', u'Greenwich', u'Amsterdam', u'Bucharest', u'Gibraltar', u'Ljubljana', u'Mariehamn', u'Podgorica', u'Stockholm', u'Volgograd', u'Christmas', u'Kerguelen', u'Mauritius', u'Enderbury', u'Galapagos', u'Kwajalein', u'Marquesas', u'Pago Pago', u'Rarotonga', u'Tongatapu', u'Argentina', u'Australia', u'Guatemala', u'Indonesia', u'Lithuania', u'Mauritius', u'Nicaragua', u'Singapore', u'Sri Lanka', u'Swaziland', u'Macedonia', u'Venezuela', u'Blantyre', u'Djibouti', u'El Aaiun', u'Freetown', u'Gaborone', u'Khartoum', u'Kinshasa', u'Monrovia', u'Ndjamena', u'Sao Tome', u'Timbuktu', u'Windhoek', u'Anguilla', u'La Rioja', u'San Juan', u'San Luis', u'Asuncion', u'Atikokan', u'Barbados', u'Dominica', u'Edmonton', u'Eirunepe', u'Ensenada', u'Kentucky', u'Mazatlan', u'Miquelon', u'Montreal', u'New York', u'Resolute', u'Santiago', u'Shiprock', u'St Johns', u'St Kitts', u'St Lucia', u'Winnipeg', u'Ashgabat', u'Calcutta', u'Damascus', u'Dushanbe', u'Istanbul', u'Jayapura', u'Katmandu', u'Makassar', u'Sakhalin', u'Shanghai', u'Tashkent', u'Tel Aviv', u'Atlantic', u'Adelaide', u'Brisbane', u'Canberra', u'Lindeman', u'Tasmania', u'Victoria', u'Belgrade', u'Brussels', u'Budapest', u'Chisinau', u'Guernsey', u'Helsinki', u'Sarajevo', u'Tiraspol', u'Uzhgorod', u'Auckland', u'Funafuti', u'Honolulu', u'Johnston', u'Pitcairn', u'Barbados', u'Botswana', u'Bulgaria', u'Cambodia', u'Cameroon', u'Colombia', u'Djibouti', u'Dominica', u'Ethiopia', u'Holy See', u'Honduras', u'Kiribati', u'Malaysia', u'Maldives', u'Mongolia', u'Pakistan', u'Paraguay', u'Portugal', u'Slovakia', u'Slovenia', u'Suriname', u'Thailand', u'Tanzania', u'Viet Nam', u'Zimbabwe', u'Anguilla', u'Abidjan', u'Algiers', u'Conakry', u'Kampala', u'Mbabane', u'Nairobi', u'Tripoli', u'America', u'Antigua', u'Cordoba', u'Mendoza', u'Tucuman', u'Ushuaia', u'Caracas', u'Cayenne', u'Chicago', u'Curacao', u'Detroit', u'Godthab', u'Grenada', u'Halifax', u'Indiana', u'Marengo', u'Winamac', u'Iqaluit', u'Managua', u'Marigot', u'Moncton', u'Nipigon', u'Noronha', u'Phoenix', u'Rosario', u'Tijuana', u'Toronto', u'Tortola', u'Yakutat', u'McMurdo', u'Rothera', u'Baghdad', u'Bahrain', u'Bangkok', u'Bishkek', u'Colombo', u'Irkutsk', u'Jakarta', u'Karachi', u'Kashgar', u'Kolkata', u'Kuching', u'Magadan', u'Nicosia', u'Rangoon', u'Tbilisi', u'Thimphu', u'Yakutsk', u'Yerevan', u'Bermuda', u'Madeira', u'Stanley', u'Andorra', u'Belfast', u'Tallinn', u'Vatican', u'Vilnius', u'Mayotte', u'Reunion', u'Chatham', u'Fakaofo', u'Gambier', u'Norfolk', u'Albania', u'Algeria', u'Armenia', u'Austria', u'Bahamas', u'Bahrain', u'Belarus', u'Belgium', u'Bolivia', u'Burundi', u'Comoros', u'Croatia', u'Denmark', u'Ecuador', u'Eritrea', u'Estonia', u'Finland', u'Georgia', u'Germany', u'Grenada', u'Hungary', u'Iceland', u'Ireland', u'Jamaica', u'Lebanon', u'Lesotho', u'Liberia', u'Morocco', u'Myanmar', u'Namibia', u'Nigeria', u'Moldova', u'Romania', u'Senegal', u'Somalia', u'Tunisia', u'Ukraine', u'Uruguay', u'Vanuatu', u'Asmara', u'Asmera', u'Bamako', u'Bangui', u'Banjul', u'Bissau', u'Douala', u'Harare', u'Kigali', u'Luanda', u'Lusaka', u'Malabo', u'Maputo', u'Maseru', u'Niamey', u'Belize', u'Bogota', u'Cancun', u'Cayman', u'Cuiaba', u'Dawson', u'Denver', u'Havana', u'Inuvik', u'Juneau', u'La Paz', u'Maceio', u'Manaus', u'Merida', u'Nassau', u'Recife', u'Regina', u'Virgin', u'Mawson', u'Palmer', u'Vostok', u'Arctic', u'Almaty', u'Anadyr', u'Aqtobe', u'Beirut', u'Brunei', u'Harbin', u'Kuwait', u'Manila', u'Muscat', u'Riyadh', u'Saigon', u'Taipei', u'Tehran', u'Thimbu', u'Urumqi', u'Azores', u'Canary', u'Faeroe', u'Currie', u'Darwin', u'Hobart', u'Sydney', u'Europe', u'Athens', u'Berlin', u'Dublin', u'Jersey', u'Lisbon', u'London', u'Madrid', u'Geneva', u'Monaco', u'Moscow', u'Prague', u'Samara', u'Skopje', u'Tirane', u'Vienna', u'Warsaw', u'Zagreb', u'Zurich', u'Chagos', u'Comoro', u'Easter', u'Kosrae', u'Majuro', u'Midway', u'Noumea', u'Ponape', u'Saipan', u'Tahiti', u'Tarawa', u'Wallis', u'Andora', u'Angola', u'Belize', u'Bhutan', u'Brazil', u'Canada', u'Cyprus', u'France', u'Gambia', u'Greece', u'Guinea', u'Guyana', u'Israel', u'Jordan', u'Kuwait', u'Latvia', u'Malawi', u'Mexico', u'Monaco', u'Norway', u'Panama', u'Poland', u'Rwanda', u'Serbia', u'Sweden', u'Turkey', u'Tuvalu', u'Uganda', u'Zambia', u'Accra', u'Cairo', u'Ceuta', u'Dakar', u'Lagos', u'Tunis', u'Jujuy', u'Aruba', u'Bahia', u'Belem', u'Boise', u'Vevay', u'Thule', u'Casey', u'Davis', u'Syowa', u'Amman', u'Aqtau', u'Dacca', u'Dhaka', u'Dubai', u'Kabul', u'Macao', u'Macau', u'Qatar', u'Seoul', u'Tokyo', u'Faroe', u'Eucla', u'Perth', u'Malta', u'Minsk', u'Paris', u'Sofia', u'Vaduz', u'Cocos', u'Efate', u'Nauru', u'Palau', u'Samoa', u'Benin', u'Chile', u'China', u'Congo', u'Egypt', u'Gabon', u'Ghana', u'Haiti', u'India', u'Italy', u'Japan', u'Kenya', u'Libya', u'Malta', u'Nauru', u'Nepal', u'Niger', u'Palau', u'Qatar', u'Samoa', u'Spain', u'Sudan', u'Syria', u'Tonga', u'Yemen', u'Lome', u'Adak', u'Atka', u'Nuuk', u'Knox', u'Lima', u'Nome', u'Asia', u'Aden', u'Baku', u'Dili', u'Gaza', u'Hovd', u'Omsk', u'Oral', u'Zulu', u'Kiev', u'Oslo', u'Bonn', u'Riga', u'Rome', u'Mahe', u'Apia', u'Fiji', u'Guam', u'Niue', u'Truk', u'Wake', u'Chad', u'Cuba', u'Fiji', u'Iran', u'Iraq', u'Mali', u'Oman', u'Peru', u'Togo', u'GMT', u'Yap']
```

**list** taken from @hmghaly's example contains **645** countries and cities

```
text = "Lorem ipsum dolor Turkey sit amet, Brussels consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do Santo Domingo eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore Tell City et dolore magna aliqua. Ut Goose Bay enim ad minim veniam, Bahrain quis nostrud exercitation New Salem ullamco laboris nisi Mongolia ut aliquip ex ea Yekaterinburg commodo consequat. Chihuahua Duis aute irure dolor in Nouakchott reprehenderit in voluptate velit Ireland esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla Lome pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat San Marino cupidatat non proident, Comoro sunt in culpa qui officia Belem deserunt mollit anim id est laborum"
```

**text** slices are classic *Lorem ipsum* text with randomly placed Country/City names, Final text is the result of concatination of the same text for 51 times, for a total of **4590** words and  **30344** letters. (Too long to write it in here, hence it the same text repeating)

Timing  is based on 1,000 (previously i tested with 1,000,000 loops) loops with each loop containing 2 repetitions:

Regex

```
regex = '('+'|'.join(list)+')'
%timeit -n 1000 -r 2 re.findall(regex, text)
1000 loops, best of 2: 3.36 ms per loop
```

---

Lambda

```
%timeit -n 1000 -r 2 filter(lambda x: x in text, list)
1000 loops, best of 2: 140 ms per loop
```

---

For loop

```
def somefunc():
    for i in list:
        if i in text:
            pass

%timeit -n 1000 -r 2 somefunc()
1000 loops, best of 2: 138 ms per loop
```

---

Radix Tree

```
from radix_tree import RadixTree
Tokens = list(set(list))

trie = RadixTree()
for token in Tokens:
    trie.insert(token, token)

def FindMatches(trie, text):
    while 0 < len(text):
        try:
            test = text[:text.index(" ")]
        except ValueError:
            test = text

        for token in trie.search_prefix(test, 100):
            if text.startswith(token):
                pass # no need to print to screen

        try:
            text = text[text.index(" ") + 1:]
        except ValueError:
            break # End of string

%timeit -n 1000 -r 2 FindMatches(trie, text)
1000 loops, best of 2: 236 ms per loop
```

---

Set and Regex

```
def SomeMoreFunc():
    rgx = '([A-Z][A-Za-z]*)' #@VoronoiPotato's approach
    filtered_text = set(re.findall(rgx, text)) #make a set of all words that starts with a capital letter 
    for x in list:
         #we split city name if it is constucted with 2 or more words, and parse it to a set, then check if all parts of the string are in the filtered text. If yes, then our city is within our text body
        if set(x.split()).issubset(filtered_text):
            pass 

%timeit -n 1000 -r 2 SomeMoreFunc()
1000 loops, best of 2: 2.81 ms per loop
```

I modified @VoronoiPotato's approach with `set` usage.

---

Token Indexing

```
def indexing_list(li):
    index_dict={}
    for i in range(len(li)):
        words=li[i].split()
        for j in range(len(words)):
            index=complex(i,j)
            word=words[j].lower()
            try:
                index_dict[word].append(index)
            except:
                index_dict[word]=[index]
    return index_dict

def someFunc():
    ind_dic = indexing_list(lst)
    text_words=text.split()
    for i in range(len(text_words)):
        tw=text_words[i].lower()
        index_dict.get(tw)


%timeit -n 1000 -r 2 someFunc()
1000 loops, best of 2: 7.41 ms per loop
```

---

With new data set, it is clear to use regex instead of simple text search, and set usage will increase performance (by cropping similar words and allowing to use `issubset` for an easier and faster cmparison). Radix Tree search gives worst result within these approaches. For the previous data set regex usage was worse than text search...

EDIT: Token Indexing results are appended. ***But***, this example only searches for single words, and there is no control with city names with two or more words.

***Also***, a dangerous bug exists for Set & Regex and Token Indexing methods, Considering city name

```
El Salvador
```

and following text:

```
Salvador Dali lorem ipsum dolor. El Dranges porte quantera.
```

both methods will match *El Salvador* with *Salvador* and *El* since theysplit words and search seperately.

Comment: This, although as the size of the list grows to the actual size he's using, lambda might lose (I don't use lambda's enough to know their growth :x)

Comment: Thank you for introducing timeit, very useful indeed

Comment: `lambda` is a camparison exapmle. what i try to say is , using `timeit` with **real** data is the best way to make the decision (:

Comment: Yes, definitely agreed, however he's also looking for different methods to test :).

Comment: I'm kinda excited to see how my method times up :)

Comment: guys can you please have a look at the code I posted in the edit to the question? Thank you

Comment: @FallenAngel I just added code to my answer, would you mind timing it as well under the same conditions?

Comment: I updated the answer with a more real time dataset and new results, also i kept old data set and results for efficiency comparrison according to dataset size

Answer (score 4):

Use a regex that checks for uppercase words in the text. That will GREATLY reduce the amount of time spent checking

[A-Z][a-z]*

Once you get a match, (an uppercase word) check if that matches first words your list, if yes, line up the next match with the second word in the list until you have a total match.

Comment: This looks like a helpful idea, I'm still looking for more such ideas, thank you :)

Comment: More ideas, look for consecutive capital lettered words many countries are more than one word, whereas few proper nouns are more than one word, Ex: Chad, or Stephen.

Comment: Since your list of predefined words is larger than the text, you might also benefit from generating a very simple hash and associating it with each item in the wordlist. When I say very simple I mean like 4 byte hash. Then run the same hash on each set of consecutive capital words. If the hash doesn't match any of the hashes in your dictionary then it's not in there.

Comment: hell you could probably get away with a 2 byte hash seeing as your numbers are lower than 5000

Comment: I'm sorry I just don't understand what hash means, I'm still a noob in programming :)

Comment: A hash is a pseudorandom number made from some data, it's frequently used as a way of identifying data. 

for example if you run a hash on the word "hmghaly" if will ALWAYS result in the same number, which might be something like 37082, and a single number is a LOT faster to check than a whole string.

Comment: So instead of using a list to store the names, you could use a dictionary and associate it with the hash value.

Comment: ID is the memory address so no it is not like ID. ID is unique, but if you get the id of country = "Georgia" and the id of state = "Georgia" it will not give you the exact same number. because it's the ID of the variable not something which describes the data in the variable.

Comment: http://ideone.com/6RRSk This is an example of what I'm talking about. As you see when the words are the same the number that comes out is exactly the same. This will help speed things up. You might think woah that's a big number it'll take forever, but computers are MUCH faster with comparing a bunch of numbers than a bunch of letters.

Comment: I like where this discussion is going..probably it might be a good idea after all to index every token within each list item and assign a unique index in it and then tokenize the text that we want to search and get the corresponding indexes and identify the consecutive ones found, can this be an option?

Comment: yep! [[{'first':1620897072}, {'second':2380425233}, {'third':2304880234}],[{'first':1620897072}, {'second':2380425233}, {'third':2304880234}]]

a list, with a list, with a dictionary. Then use Fallen Angels suggestion to time it and compare how fast each technique is.

Answer (score 2):

You may find a [Radix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree) to be the most efficient.

<strike>The basic idea is to convert the text being searched into a tree that's efficient for finding other strings in.  However, since the tokens you are searching for have whitespace in them, you'll have to do some fiddling to figure out the best definition of a token.</strike>

For example, every grouping of X words is one token, where X is the maximum number of words in a given item you are searching for.  Example:  The tree for "Everything is green over here." with a token length of 3 words would contain "Everything is green", "is green over", and "green over here".

Given the example in the question (posted after the above was written), I ended up reversing what I suggested above in the code below.  The tokens being searched for are added to the Trie/Radix tree, then the text string is progressively searched for them.  The striked-out lines above *may* be more efficient if you have less tokens and more text to search.

Here's a [Python implementation of a radix tree](http://code.google.com/p/python-radix-tree/source/browse/#svn/trunk), so you wouldn't necessarily have to write it yourself, and here's an implementation using that Radix tree:

```
from radix_tree import RadixTree
Tokens = list(set([.....the list in the question.....])) # 'El Salvador' is listed twice, this is to make it unique easily.

trie = RadixTree()
for token in Tokens:
   trie.insert(token, token)

def FindMatches(trie, text):
   while 0 < len(text):
      try:
         test = text[:text.index(" ")]
      except ValueError:
         test = text

      for token in trie.search_prefix(test, 100):
         if text.startswith(token):
            print token

      try:
         text = text[text.index(" ") + 1:]
      except ValueError:
         break # End of string

FindMatches(trie, "I went to New York and New Orleans and London and United States, Canada, and Egypt, Saudi Arabia")
```

Note:  New Orleans is not in the list of tokens, and Canada and Egypt are not being found by the Trie inside `search_prefix` because "," is included in the token from the test string.

Comment: Thank you, this seems promising

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth trying the regex implementation on PyPI to see if that's faster:

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex

I'm thinking in particular of the "named lists" feature.

Answer (score -1):

Regardless of the actual **parsing** method, since your data is so large, you're going to have them in files, which you probably already are doing in some way. Here's a way I think is most efficient in getting your data into python:

`search.txt` - your strings to search for, `searchterms` will be a list of strings

`large.txt` - the text to search through, `large` will be a single string

```
 with open('search.txt') as x: searchterms = x.readlines()
 with open('large.txt') as x: large = x.read()
```

I suggest you iterate over `searchterms` to find your matches in `large` as HussainNagri suggested in his answer:

```
for i in searchterms:
  if i in large:
    print i, " found in text"
```

Comment: Roughly 75 kb of text isn't exactly gut wrenching for a modern computer.

Comment: I agree... but that's not at all what I'm saying here. I encourage you to actually read a post before downvoting someone because they suggest using **files** to **hold large amounts of data**.

Comment: It's tangential to the question. It doesn't actually help him solve the act of searching the information.

Comment: Ok sure, but since the OP didn't specify an input method, I figured I provide a good choice for getting that data into python efficiently (efficiency seems to be his main agenda). Also, *I still answered the question* at the end of my post.

Comment: Once it's loaded into memory it takes just as fast whether it's stated in code or in a file, and that answer is functionally equivalent to the first answer posted. I'm not trying to be mean, I just don't think it's a very constructive answer. If you can edit it to be more helpful I'll remove my downvote.

Comment: I did my best to update it. It's worth noting that the first part of my answer was originally an edit to @HussainNagri's answer, but he refused the edit, so I felt compelled to share it as an answer.

Comment: Edits typically are reserved for grammatical changes or editing for clarity. This would probably be best placed as a comment.